# ExoPlayer AVI files

Tags: android, avi, exoplayer

I'm using `ExoPlayer` to play video & audio files in my app. Recently I've discovered that `ExoPlayer` does not support AVI files.
What I'm asking for is the way to make it support AVI.
As per [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/745), they are not going to add AVI support, but there is some way to play AVI with some deprecated API.

Comment: You could also convert your AVI files to MP4. Better compression and quality.

Comment: @Wildcopper ,I'm playing files from URLs, they are not static.

Comment: late to the party, but this question does not really show effort in solving the issue (given also the size of the feature), and does not seem as a good fit for a single question